# Python 3 Append to list from file

Tags: python-3.x, list, file

**Question:**
I have a script that can read my x and y clicks that store into a file What I'm trying to do is read the file and store the clicks into a list Im not to sure how I can do that Im kinda new to python and not sure if that is possible or if it may work better doing an array, dictionary etc.. But i've tried other options and I have not found what I was looking for

**Code:**

```
a_file = open("filePath", "r")
li1 = []
x = a_file.readlines() 
li1.append(x)

# @ Trying to get a values in file to a list loop
                 
for x in li1:
    print(x)

a_file.close()
```

**What X Out puts:**

```
[834.9296875 172.890625 834.69921875 172.890625]
```

**X's Out put I need:**

```
[834.9296875, 172.890625, 834.69921875, 172.890625]
```

Comment: What does the file content look like?

Comment: 0.0
0.0
0.0 
0.0
Just like that, Ive gotten to the point now where its ['0.0\n', '0.00.0\n'] Just  like i was looking for. Just now trying to remove the \n from the list to be able to use it. Then i'll try to update the list when its called later on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably you will then want to do something with the list.
Most times it is better to avoid creating a whole big data structure in memory just to consume it by element later.

Files can be iterated on directly, line by line:

```
with open("path") as a_file:
    for line in a_file:
        print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```py
with open("path", "r") as file:
    li1 = file.readlines()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help I appreciate it!!